# Bring the data from one table to another grouped by ID and Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, metadata

I have a data frame which look like this:

```
ID       Date       Item          Sales
1        1-Dec       A             10
1        2-Dec       B             15
1        3-Dec       C             20
2        1-Dec       A             20
2        2-Dec       C             10
3        1-Dec       A             5
3        2-Dec       A             15
```

And another table which looks like this:

```
  ID    Date   Input      Output
   1    1-Dec   A         A,B
   2    2-Dec   A         A,B,C
   3    3-Dec   B         B,C
```

Now based on ID and Date i have to pick the sales from table 1 and wherever Input is not equal to output it should calculate the sum difference between two sales, so output table will be like this:

```
       ID    Date   Input     Output        Diff.
       1    1-Dec   A         A,B           10-0=10           
       2    2-Dec   A         A,B,C         0-0-10=-10
       3    3-Dec   B         B,C           0-0=0
```

In row 1 output is 10 because in sales table sales for A for Dec-1 and ID 1 is 10 whereas Data for B is not available so can consider it as 0.
In row 2 output is -10 because for Dec-2 and output 2 Sales for B and C is not given
Similarly for Row 3 output is 0, because for B and C data is not present.

Comment: can you explain the row 2 output again? I cant understand how the difference is -10.

Comment: for Row2, input was A and output was A,B,C but in the table1 we have value for C only, thats why considered A and B as zero.

Comment: Yes i have 3 rows for Dec-2 but with different IDs, so output should be grouped by ID and Date @Aryerez

Comment: What if you will have **3** different values for the same "ID" and "Date"? How do you define "Diff." there?

Answer (score 0):

Idea is [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25+) rows in `df2` by splitted `Output` column, so possible [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, then multiple by `-1` all rows of sales without first per group with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and last aggregate by `join` and `sum`:

```
df2 = df2.assign(Output = df2['Output'].str.split(',')).explode('Output')

df = (df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'Item':'Output'}), 
                how='left',
                on=['ID','Date','Output'])
         .fillna({'Sales':0}))
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['ID','Date','Input']), 'Sales'] *=  -1

df = (df.groupby(['ID','Date','Input'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'Output':','.join, 'Sales':'sum'})
        .rename(columns={'Sales':'Diff'}))
print (df)
   ID   Date Input Output  Diff
0   1  1-Dec     A    A,B  10.0
1   2  2-Dec     A  A,B,C -10.0
2   3  3-Dec     B    B,C   0.0
```